# Working with node-sets in Xpath 1.0

Tags: xpath

I'm working with CALS tables which has multiple colspec elements with tgroup element as a parent. 
In xpath 2.0 the following works:

```
colspec/substring-before( @colwidth , '*' )
```

In xpath 1.0 it complains: Unexpected token - "substring-before( @colwid"

There has to be a way to accomplish this. I need to sum the number values before the asterisk so that I can convert the relative column widths to percentages. At this point in the day I can't even think of an inelegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In xpath 1.0 it complains: Unexpected
>   token - "substring-before( @colwid"

That's because right term of `/` step operator can't be a function call in XPath 1.0 (This is a feature of XPath 2.0!).

You have to develop a recursive template.

Comment: `substring-before(colspec/@colwidth, '*')` will work in XSLT/XPATH 1.0, but as @Alehandro points out, it would require a recursive template in order to calculate the sum of those values.